# Zend Framework Installation

Tags: zend-framework, installation, virtual-hosts

i am installing Zend Framework.i set up all virtual host  and virtual domain settings both in WINDOWS and APACHE.
when im gonna run my project , it will display "server not found"
is it because of my firewall?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try and visit the site using the IP address it's meant to be listening on (i.e http://192.168.1.2/ changing the IP as appropriate for your machine). Does a default Apache "This works!" page show at all?